# Фоновое изображение, которое при скролле не изменяется

Tags: html, css

Как сделать фоновое изображение. Что-бы когда ты скроллишь `body` вниз оно не менялось. И полностью заливало экран.

Я сделал вот так. Через `html`.

```
  <body style="overflow:hidden;">
        <section style="overflow-y:auto;">
              <header></header>
              <section>
                    //Content
              </section>
        </section>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body{
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     background-attachment: fixed;
  }
```

http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size

http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-attachment